# Manually show validations on save with WPF datagrid

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid

Using the WPF datagrid from WPFToolkit I want to show errors *only* during the save operation.  Currently it seems to validate when you move off the row, hit enter, etc.

There are two types of row level validations I need to perform:

1) Before service call to ensure fields on object are set.

2) After service call, to show any service validation.  (Note I have a way to map the service validation to the object that was sent - but need a way to highlight the row error with the service validation)

Seems to be two options:  a) use default ValidationRule WPF grid framework to highlight the before/after row validations by forcing validation to be rerun somehow?  b) roll my own validation

My question is there a way to do row level validations on multiple rows manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding to an INotifyProperty you can manually call PropertyChanged(propertyName) to force a re-validation. Since you're using a DataGrid, you might need to use CollectionChanged() instead.